# the Capital and Small Letter in Title

Tags: capitalization

I am confused about when to write capital letter or small letter in a title. Like the title above, I think

> The, and, in are **perp**, so they can be small letters.

Am I right? Can someone clarify the rules about the **Capital and Small Letter in Title**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very interesting question. Nevertheless, it's debatable as well. Some writers prefer to capitalize some words whereas others don't.

Let's look at a few points here -

> a) Prefer capitalizing the *first and last word* of a title.
>   b) Avoid capitalization if it's scientific name or botanical name for the second word. For instance - *Asparagus racemosus.*
>   c) Capitalize all adjectives, most of pronouns, nouns and adverbs. Capitalize *verbs* as well if you want to emphasize them.
>   d) Try avoiding capitalization of very short words (conjunctions?) such as *and* or *or.* Also *be*, *are*, *was*, *were*, *as*, *to*, and so on **[This is debatable in particular]**.
>  
>   e) Avoid capitals to the definite and indefinite articles
>   f) Capitalize all the words if they are of five or more letters.

More information [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/capitalizing-titles?page=1).

Comment: (f) is debatable as well. Some style guides will instruct to NOT capitalize prepositions (even longer ones, such as _across_ or _between_).

Comment: @J.R. The question itself is debatable (as stated) but then now corrected the d point.