# What the hell does “Funnier than Hell” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there something I’m missing about the meaning of “hell”? “Funnier than hell” seems, in typical context, to mean *very* funny, but I can’t find anything funny about hell. Can somebody please explain this?

*Note: I’m posting an answer to this question, simultaneously with posting the question itself. I feel no need to “accept” my own answer, I invite others to answer the question as well and I welcome comments.*

Comment: There isn't really any "meaning" to ***hell*** here. It's just the most common "swearword" added as an intensifier, in usages such as [*funny as hell*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22funny+as+hell%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [*funny as heck*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22funny+as+heck%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), [*funny as fuck*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22funny+as+fuck%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: I agree, I used different words, but I tried to say as much in my answer. I don't know that it's the most common intensifier, but it's certainly one of the most innocent of the common ones.

Comment: Obviously there are a ***helluva lot*** of contexts where people want something a bit less crude than f**k.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I used a common example. If you would rather put it a different way, please do.

Comment: Why did you post the question if you already knew the answer? Did you just want to chat about it or something?

Comment: That's actually something that Stack Exchange really approves. I know it's a bit unusual, but it's very encouraged. It's just a way to express things that about which you have something to say.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: To be honest, I don't really think it's worth asking the question "What does '**hell**' mean in this usage?". But for what it's worth, firstly I think *"funny as hell"* is far more common than *"funnier than hell"*, and secondly I think both of them are far less common than they were 50-100 years ago. The thing is *"as XXXX as fuck"* works with a much wider range of XXXX's than *"...as hell"* - usually you're either going to swear or you're not, so you might as well use the more generic word. (Or just *"really bloody XXXX"*, if you genuinely need something a bit less crude.)

Comment: I hear it all the time. "That's funnier than hell, hahaha!" By far and away, that's the usage I hear most often. I hear "funny as hell" too. I'm not sure I understand a significant difference between the two.

Comment: @Jay http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/958/stretching-the-teacher-student-role

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could this be a cultural thing? I have never been to the UK. Here, where I am today, I hear "funnier than hell" all the time. Maybe it's because I'm a middle aged woman and people are reluctant to use stronger language in my presence?

Comment: @Jolenealaska: I don't really know. Here's [an NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=funny+as+hell%2Cfunnier+than+hell&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfunny%20as%20hell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfunnier%20than%20hell%3B%2Cc0) supporting my feeling that WW2 was the heyday for *funny as hell*, and that *funnier than hell* is quite rare by comparison. I must admit that second one in particular sounds to me more like something a Chinese student, say, with quite good English skills might come out with, rather than an actual native speaker today.

Comment: I don't really have any response to that except to ask, is there a difference?

Comment: I could replace the words "Funnier than Hell" with "Funny as Hell". Would that cause any significant changes to my question or response?

Answer (score 4):

There are two very distinct usages of the word “hell”. In the first usage, the word only means what you know it means.

From Google:

noun: hell; noun: Hell

1. a place regarded in various religions as a spiritual realm of evil and suffering, often traditionally depicted as a place of perpetual fire beneath the earth where the wicked are punished after death.
   -synonyms: the netherworld, the Inferno, the infernal regions, the abyss
   -antonyms: heaven
2. a state or place of great suffering; an unbearable experience.
   "I've been through hell"
   -synonyms: a misery, torture, agony, a torment, a nightmare, an ordeal
   -antonyms: paradise

Used in this way, the word isn’t swearing. Just use it as a normal noun. There are people that would disagree with that, those people might suggest that hell is *always* a “bad word”. I can only say that I consider that attitude to be extreme. You’re not likely to encounter that attitude in the US except in enclaves of piety. Further, there is no need to self-censor the use of that word because children or your mother-in-law are present. It’s just a word.

The second usage if the word is as an exclamation. Used in this way, it *is* swearing. It’s a *baby* swearword. Using the word “hell” is often the first swearing children will do. The word “dammit” is right there with it. Kids are kind of testing the waters of the big bad world of grown-up swearing when they first start using those two words.
“Hell” *is* swearing, but it’s relatively benign, it’s frequently used when people feel like swearing, but don’t want to be extreme about it.

The word “hell” is kind of the little tag-along brother of the big-bad swearword of them all, you know the one, it‘s four letters long and starts with “F”.  If that is at all unclear, go to YouTube and search for George Carlin. He actually explains English swearing very well, just understand that his videos are **Not Suitable for Work!**

So “hell” (like his big, tough, older brother) as a swearword can be twisted to say pretty much anything, even things that make no sense. “Funnier than hell” is just one example of that. It’s just a way of interjecting a fairly innocent swearword.

Comment: Agreed. I'd say that for a religious person who believes in Hell, reference to Hell itself (1) is never swearing. "I've been through hell" (defn 2) may mildly offend such a person in reference to what would surely be a trivial suffering compared to actual hell (defn 1). Whether that means it "is swearing" or not is difficult to say.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was inarticulate. What I mean is that I think the reason someone very religious would be offended by definition (2) of hell is that it trivializes definition (1), and not that it "is a swear word." (In the same way that I don't like, say, the words "genocide" or "torture" being thrown around lightly.) I still feel inarticulate; I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your question and answer!

Comment: Believe it or not, I struggled with the word "piety". I even brought it up in chat before I posted. I agree that it gets a bit touchy there. If you've got a better way to say it, I'm all ears. I understand too about qualms with definition 2. Just bringing it up (as you have) adds to the discussion. It's not a black and white thing.

Comment: @hunter Note that the second **definition** is not the second **usage** but an aspect of the first usage (I stumbled over that myself!). That doesn't make your comments invalid - I just point out in case you misunderstood, as I did initially, that definition 2 is not what Jolenealaska is saying "*is* swearing".

Comment: @nxx Thank you. Yes, the second definition is a part of the first usage. It is my opinion that using the word that way is *not* swearing, but it does subvert the theological usage.

Comment: @Jolenealaska They are really interesting definitions. Def 1 is basically def 2, but situated within (certain) religion(s). **H**ell for def 1 and **h**ell for def 2 is how I've usually seen them used. I think there are many for whom def 2 "subverts"  as you say or completely denies def 1 - perhaps in that it indicates that there can be "a hell" or multiple "hells" rather than the one "Hell" - thus making it akin to swearing.

Comment: PS This reminds me of Bart Simpson "swearing" by saying "hell damn fart" and "crap boobs crap" :D

Comment: @nxx I remember a conversation on a school bus. I couldn't quite bring myself to say hell, so I said, "H..E..double toothpicks"

Comment: As a Fundamentalist Christian who regularly associates with Fundamentalist Christians: Yes, I can't imagine someone being offended by use of the word "Hell" in definition 1. As to definition 2 ... Someone might be offended by a person saying, "I only got a 1% pay raise. I was raped!" That is, someone might think you are trivializing a very serious issue by using the word in such a context. I think we would all agree that "It was an X of a bad day" -- fill in "hell" or the f-word or numerous other words for X -- is swearing. "I went through X today" is not really very far from that. ...

Comment: ... If you were truly painting a serious analogy, people might consider it inappropriate but not swearing. Like, "The land at the base of the volcano, with rivers of molten lava, the air filled with smoke, and the screams of those who had been unable to escape, seemed like a scene from Hell" -- I don't anyone would call that swearing. But, "Sitting through Sally's poetry reading is like being in Hell" -- borderline at best.

Comment: @Jay Point taken!

Comment: RE "say pretty much anything": Sure. I've often heard people say, "It's hotter than Hell today", which is presumably an exaggeration but makes sense. But I've also often heard people say, "It's colder than Hell today", to which the only logical reply is, "Well, yeah, by the teachings of any religion I know."

Comment: That's the point. When used that way, it's swearing. It no longer has that theological meaning. "Funnier than hell" is the same way.

Comment: Using "as [adjective] as hell" or "[comparative adjective] than hell" are always examples of hyperbole, since hell is a state beyond any known true state.

Answer (score 0):

I see this phrase in a different way.

*Funnier than Hell* has two perplexing words - funny and hell! To my (and probably to many) surprise, [hell](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=hell) and [Hell](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=hell) have different meanings.

I think this phrase takes a particular meaning from many as mentioned in dictionaries.

> [funny](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=funny) - Beyond or deviating from the usual or expected OR not as expected (usually in **negation**) 
>   [hell](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=hell) - Any place of pain and turmoil OR A cause of difficulty and suffering 
>   [Hell](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=hell) - (Christianity) the abode of Satan and the forces of evil; where sinners suffer eternal punishment OR (religion) the world of the dead

So, when you get into the trouble which is not expected and it has caused you a difficulty or suffering, this phrase makes sense.

**Please note** - As stated by WordWeb, the phrase better go with *hell* and not *Hell*. Having this said, the sentence preferably have *Funnier/funnier than hell (and not Hell). **Also note that** if the phrase is the title, it's fine because [in the title, we do capitalize the first letter of words](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16304/the-capital-and-small-letter-in-title). This means the *hell* will be written as *Hell* but would serve the meaning of *hell* as in the dictionary!

Comment: This negative interpretation is one that is _never_ intended by any native speaker of BrE or AmE, but it is very interesting you point it out. It reminds me of some confusing miscommunication with an Indian friend of mine when she said she would miss a deadline and I told her "that's too bad". I meant to tell her not to worry about it, as it really wasn't that important. She interpreted it literally as "that is very, very bad". It took me some time to figure out why she was so unhappy with my reaction :)

Comment: @oerkelens if you tell me that it's too bad I would not sleep for that night thinking I lost yet as a client.

Comment: I have become very careful using the expression when communicating with Indian acquaintances because the same happened to that friend of mine. Her initial reaction to a heartfelt "WTF" was also one of panic :)